# Show number of records in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using code that paginates a table grid with data from mysql. This is working fine. However, the one problem I have is that the number of records to show is coded into the script.

What I need to do is give the user an option to display say [5] [10][20] in a dropdown. Would this be possible with the code I have posted. Many thanks

```
$('table.paginated').each(function() {
  var currentPage = 0;
  var numPerPage = 8;
  var $table = $(this);
  $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
    $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
  });
  $table.trigger('repaginate');
  var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
  var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
  for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
    $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
      newPage: page
    }, function(event) {
      currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
      $table.trigger('repaginate');
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
  }
  $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This does what you want, I reckon. I added the 5,10,20 options as clickable links, but I now realise you asked for them in a dropdown. The principle remains the same, though - it relies on the fact that `numPerPage` can be changed within the closure of the click event

[update: changed to use dropdown]

```js
    $('table.paginated').each(function() {
        var currentPage = 0;
        var numPerPage = 8;
        var numPages;
        var $table = $(this);
var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
        $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
$pager.empty();
            var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
            numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);

        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
            $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                newPage: page
            }, function(event) {
                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
        }
        $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');



            $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        });
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        
        

        var $numberPicker = $('<div class="numberPicker"></div>');
        var dropdown = $('<select></select>');
        $([5,10,20]).each(function() {
            var $num = this;
            $('<option></option>').text(this).attr('value',this).appendTo(dropdown);
        });
        dropdown.bind('change', function() {
            numPerPage = this.value;
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
        }).insertAfter($table);    

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <table class='paginated'>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>17</td></tr>
        <tr><td>18</td></tr>
        <tr><td>19</td></tr>
        <tr><td>20</td></tr>
        <tr><td>21</td></tr>
        <tr><td>22</td></tr>
        <tr><td>23</td></tr>
        <tr><td>24</td></tr>
        <tr><td>25</td></tr>
        <tr><td>26</td></tr>
        <tr><td>27</td></tr>
        <tr><td>28</td></tr>
        <tr><td>29</td></tr>
        <tr><td>30</td></tr>
        <tr><td>31</td></tr>
        <tr><td>32</td></tr>
        <tr><td>33</td></tr>
        <tr><td>34</td></tr>
        <tr><td>35</td></tr>
        <tr><td>36</td></tr>
        <tr><td>37</td></tr>
        <tr><td>38</td></tr>
        <tr><td>39</td></tr>
        <tr><td>40</td></tr>
        <tr><td>41</td></tr>
        <tr><td>42</td></tr>
        <tr><td>43</td></tr>
        <tr><td>44</td></tr>
        <tr><td>45</td></tr>
        <tr><td>46</td></tr>
        <tr><td>47</td></tr>
        <tr><td>48</td></tr>
        <tr><td>49</td></tr>
        <tr><td>50</td></tr>
        <tr><td>51</td></tr>
        <tr><td>52</td></tr>
        <tr><td>53</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much chris. Just one thing. Would it be possible to have the options in a dropdown. As I am new user to scripting, an example would be good. Would make selection easier for users. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help chris. Much appreciate. If you get a minute and can guide me how to use your code in dropdown, i'll be very grateful. cheers

Comment: I've edited this to use a dropdown now. I assumed, from the quality of your original code, that you were experienced at scripting, but I guess that was a faulty assumption.

Comment: Thanks very much chris

Comment: Just as an afterthought chris and should have checked at the time, but when you select amount of records, it dosn't update the number of pages. So if you go to the last record it is blank. If you have a fix for this could you please post update. Many thanks

Comment: Try moving the lines `var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);` into the repaginate function.

Comment: Chris gives me error of: ReferenceError: numPages is not defined. This is what I used: $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
    
    $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
  });

Comment: you're trying to access numPerPage before it's set. Set it first. Ie, move the lines starting `var` above the lines that try to use them.

Comment: Chris It would be easire if you could just update my code with your answer. I think that would be easier. many thanks

Comment: It would be easier if I wrote it all for you, yes. But at some point you are going to need to actually know how it works I'm afraid.  And debugging `numPages is not defined` is a good place to start. It's not difficult to see what the error means, or how to resolve it.

Comment: Appreciate your comment chris. However, on this occasion I am totally confused as what ever I move I get error. I just thought I would learn by an example. Thanks

Comment: OK, I've made another edit to my answer. The formatting is messed up now, but I think it works

Comment: Many thanks for that chris. I notice that you have add code that wasn't previously there. such as: `$pager.empty();` I know what undefined means but was getting confused as to where to create it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, I had to move all the code that writes the pager elements into the repaginate function. Then I needed to empty the pager so as not to duplicate the links.